# Stackoverflow data differs when viewing on different browsers. Why?

Tags: discussion, area-51

I've noticed that personal info (e.g. reputation) displays with different data depending on which OS I log in here from. E.g. on Windows I may have a reputation of 26 while on my iPad I'm at 51, even though I'm logged in at the same time on both and the browsers area refreshed.

Just curious about how Stackoverflow puts out different data to different kinds of machines.

Comment: Caching. It's always caching.

Comment: Most of us are smarter on our IPads than when using Windows. This is a general known fact. ;)

Comment: Ah! I forgot that!

Answer (score 5):

You may have ended up with unregistered extra accounts.

Check that the profile id is the same on both platforms. When you write an answer and enter your email in at that time, you get a cookie-based unregistered account.

You may also have used a different openid there and gotten two similar-looking accounts. Go to your profile on each and select "my logins", and ensure that they are the same.

I doubt it's caching here.